# Huge difference in admob Requests and Impressions, is my code placement wrong?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am using admob Interstitial ads in one of my app and getting a huge difference in Requests and Impressions. With 1.1 million requests I'm getting only 256K impressions. I generally load an Interstitial ad when user clicks the back button. Is my code placement wrong or what could be the possible reason behind this? I am using admob only, no mediation.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(interstitialAd.isLoaded()){
        interstitialAd.show();
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I had the same issue at first. You said that you load the Ad when the user clicks the back button.

1. Always load the ad at the beginning of the activity so that when the click method gets activated, the Ad is already available.

My ad is now at 99.73 percent after I made that change.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

**I hope you get the point**

Ad **requests** are the number of times the app **requested** ads from **AdMob**.

Ad **impressions** are the number of times at least 1 pixel of the ads are **shown** at the app.

There are always a **difference between those metrics** due to many cases like **slow internet connection** at which user wouldn't be served or shown the ads even though the ad requests are made to AdMob. Hence you see the difference.

The request is an attempt to show an ad. Potential advertisers may buy or not this particular requests, it could be filled with an ad or not.

**The impression is counted after the ad has been delivered to the user's browser.**